# the meaning of 'waiting on Beyonce' part in this sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-meaning

I have seen the sentence like 'I have been waiting on Beyonce to call me.' on the internet.
And I can't understand the meaning of 'waiting on Beyonce' part.
What is the meaning of the sentence 'I have been waiting on Beyonce to call me.'
Please tell me.

Comment: One of the definitions of the [phrasal verb **wait on**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wait-on) is "to wait for a particular thing to happen."  Does that help?

Comment: Have you heard of the singer named "Beyoncé".

Comment: Try to cite your source.  I assume it is something like this buzzfeed article https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/krystieyandoli/love-is-blind-carlton-diamond-reunion-special

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44452/wait-on-vs-wait-for

Answer (score 1):

"Waiting *for*..." is the more common usage in some regions. E.G., "I'm waiting for a phone call." "Waiting on..." is perhaps more common in the U.K.

In other context, it could mean helping or serving, e.g., a server stating, "I'm waiting on table three."